# Como posso colocar vários valores no parâmetros dessa função?

Tags: javascript, funções

Tenho um código que tem os parâmetros já definidos. O q eu queria é poder fazer essa multiplicação com a quantidade de parâmetros que eu quisesse. Como faço pra colocar quantos parâmetros eu quiser ?

```
function limite (n1,n2){
if (n1,n2>=0){
    console.log (Math.imul(n1,n2))
} else{
    console.log('ops')
}
```

}

```
limite(5,5)
```

Nesse n1 e n2 eu queria q quando eu fosse chamar a função, eu pudesse colocar quantos parâmetros eu quiser

Answer (score 3):

Para que você consiga isso será necessário alterar um pouco o código que lida com dois números para lidar com um array.

#### Recebendo um número indefinido de argumentos

```
function limite(...numbers) {
    // TODO...
}
```

desta forma conseguimos receber um número ilimitado de argumentos, mas só mudar isso não basta, obviamente. O argumento numbers será um `array`.

O método Math.imul só está preparado para receber dois argumentos, então se você quer multiplicar todos os números, teremos que fazer um [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Multiplicaremos sempre o total da multiplicação anterior pelo próximo número (que pelo que entendi é o que precisa):

```
function limite(...args) {
    return args.reduce((total, current) => total * current);
}
```

#### Exemplo completo

```js
function limite(...numbers) {
        return numbers.reduce((total, current) => total * current);
}

console.log(limite(3, 3, 3)); // Resumindo: 3 * 3 * 3 = 27
```

#### Validação de números negativos ou não-numéricos

Como em seu exemplo você adiciona uma camada de validação para verificar se o número é maior que zero, vamos adaptar nosso exemplo para isso também. Mas é importante saber que isso tem um custo de processamento; dependendo da quantidade de argumentos que você vai passar, você pode ter problemas de performance comparando um a um. Supondo que não seja o caso,  vamos verificar se cada valor do array é um número.

```js
function limite(...numbers) {
        for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (typeof numbers[i] !== "number" || numbers[i] < 0) {
         throw new Error('Argumento ' + (i + 1) + ' inválido. Deve ser numérico e maior que zero');
      }
    }
        return numbers.reduce((total, current) => total * current);
}

console.log(limite(3, 3, 3, "a")); // Retornará um erro pois o argumento número 4 é inválido
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript já suporta múltiplos parâmetros **nativamente** com [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

```js
function func1() {
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  console.log(arguments[1]);
  console.log(arguments[2]);
  console.log(arguments[3]);
  console.log(arguments[4]);
  console.log(arguments[5]); // Não existe, retornará undefined
}

func1(1, 2, 3, 5, 6);
```

Por fim para iterar basta usar um `for(;;)` ou qualquer função auxiliar para *Arrays* poderá atingir o seu objetivo especifico.

Exemplo:

```js
function func1() {
  for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) {
     console.log('índice:', i, 'valor:', arguments[i]);
  }
}

func1(1, 2, 3, 5, 6);
```

É possível usar spread? Sim, é possível, mas não tem muita vantagem, a não ser que você deseje algo mais verboso.

---

Nota: essa parte `(n1,n2>=0)` está errado, se alterar o n1 para -1 ainda sim irá retornar `true`, independente do valor:

```js
var n1 = -1; n2 = 0;
console.log((n1,n2>=0));
```